# Echoing php inside javascript

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

Trying to display the message in a MySQL table to all users' screens using xmlhttp, toastr alert and php.

I use `xmlhttp.open("GET","includes/ajax/user/general/messages.php?username=<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>",true);` which is where the SQL is and I put this on a 5 second loop so it checks `messages.php` every 5 seconds.

After I then do:

```
xmlhttp.send();

$.toast({
heading: <?php echo json_encode($messageInfo['title']); ?>,
text: <?php echo json_encode($messageInfo['message']); ?>,
position: 'top-right',
loaderBg: '#ff6849',
icon: <?php echo json_encode($messageInfo['type']); ?>,
hideAfter: 6000,
stack: 6
});
```

However this only outputs 'null' as the heading and 'null' as the text.

messages.php:

```
<?php

    if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
        die;
    }

    ob_start();
    require_once '../../../app/config.php';
    require_once '../../../app/init.php';

    if (!empty($maintaince)){
        die();
    }


    if (!($user -> LoggedIn()) || !($user -> notBanned($odb)) || !($user->isAdmin($odb))){
        die();
    }


    $username = $_GET['username'];

    if(empty($username)){
        die();
    }

    $SQLGetInfo = $odb -> prepare("SELECT * FROM `live_messages` WHERE id = 1");
    $SQLGetInfo -> execute(array($_SESSION['ID']));
    $messageInfo = $SQLGetInfo -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $type = $messageInfo['type'];
    $title = $messageInfo['title'];
    $message = $messageInfo['message'];


?>
```

EDIT: If I put the PHP code which is in `messages.php` directly into the file which runs this script then it fetches from the database successfully however this is no help as i'm looking to display messages in real time.

EDIT: 
Full script

```
<script>

                window.setInterval(function(){

                    var xmlhttp;

                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){

                        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

                    }

                    else{

                        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

                    }

                    xmlhttp.open("GET","includes/ajax/user/general/messages.php?username=<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>",true);



                    xmlhttp.send();

                    $.toast({
                    heading: <?php echo json_encode($title); ?>,
                    text: <?php echo json_encode($message); ?>,
                    position: 'top-right',
                    loaderBg: '#ff6849',
                    icon: <?php echo json_encode($type); ?>,
                    hideAfter: 6000,
                    stack: 6
                    });


                }, 5000);


                </script>
```

Comment: So you are executing `php` to then run `ajax` to call `php`.... why not just render the data from the first `php` call? If you have already created a `php` session before making the `ajax` call why would you need to use `php` to pass anything into `javascript`? Your method to approach this confuses me. Maybe I am misunderstanding or you are over complicating things.

Comment: Even doing the following doesn't work:
`<?php echo json_encode($title); ?>
<?php echo json_encode($message); ?>
<?php echo json_encode($type); ?>`

Comment: He wants to check it every five seconds

Comment: @mmdts for now yes, however will probably change this to a higher value.

Comment: I was just answering the question of NewToJS

Comment: I can't have a full picture of how he organized his code, but the issue is definitely in the fact that you aren't echoing anything. @Zac Ram, I'd appreciate if you post your full code organized into files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have slight misunderstanding of how to use XHR requests.
XHR requests work similarly to browser requests, and with the code you've shown us you have no handler registered for the response.

See the POST example on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send

Now, in order to access the data processed by `messages.php` you're going to have to send back a proper JSON response.

I.E.

`header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($messageInfo);`

Which will then be passed back to your XHR requests load handler.

W3 Schools has an "okay" example of how its all put together: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_php.asp

EDIT: I've provided a working code example that is essentially a direct copy and paste of the content in the w3schools link.

`test.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script>
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        // When the XHR Request receives a response from the server
        // this function will be called.
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

                // This function is necessary to parse the JSON sent back
                // from the server.
                // Note: It can fail, so you'll want to make sure it actually parsed
                // the response.
                var message = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

                // Here is an example of how you would use it with your $.toast call
                // $.toast({
                //     heading: message.heading,
                //     text: message.body,
                //     position: 'top-right',
                //     loaderBg: '#ff6849',
                //     icon: message.type,
                //     hideAfter: 6000,
                //     stack: 6
                // });

                document.getElementById("toast_title").innerHTML = message.title;
                document.getElementById("toast_body").innerHTML = message.body;
            }
        };

        xmlhttp.open("GET", "demo_file.php", true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="toast_title"></div>
    <div id="toast_body"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

`demo_file.php`

```
/**
 * All of your logic to get the messages
 */

$message = [
    'title' => 'This is basically the same thing as the W3 Schools link.',
    'body' => 'After JSON Encoding this array, and echoing it out it will be sent to your XHR requests onreadystatechange function'
];

// Its important that the call to header goes before ANY output.
// otherwise it will bomb.
header("Content-Type: application/json;");
echo json_encode($message);
```

Comment: I have just added the whole script I used to the question

Comment: My answer is still valid. The PHP code you are injecting into your call to `$.toast` has already been processed when the XHR request goes out. This is why you need a response callback to handle the XHR request.

Comment: Where would i put `header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($messageInfo);` ?

Comment: At the very bottom of `messages.php`

Comment: Still doesn't work - outputs 'null' as the title of the toastr and that's all

Comment: that code works great and i can probably work around it so it works with toastr however now when i add all the php logic I had before starting from `if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
  die;
 }` to `$message = $messageInfo['message'];` and look in console it says 500 error however when I visit the php direct in a new tab it displays a white page

Comment: Sounds like you're hitting the `die` statement. You can `echo` something out before that to be certain. Otherwise, without looking at all your code and debugging it for you I'm not sure I can help much farther.

Answer (score 0):

may be

```
<script>
var username = "<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>";
var title = JSON.parse("<?php echo json_encode($title); ?>");
var message = JSON.parse("<?php echo json_encode($message); ?>");
var type = JSON.parse("<?php echo json_encode($type); ?>");

window.setInterval(function(){

                var xmlhttp;

                if (window.XMLHttpRequest){

                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

                }

                else{

                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

                }

                xmlhttp.open("GET","includes/ajax/user/general/messages.php?username="+username ,true);



                xmlhttp.send();

                $.toast({
                heading: title,
                text: message,
                position: 'top-right',
                loaderBg: '#ff6849',
                icon: type,
                hideAfter: 6000,
                stack: 6
                });
            }, 5000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why people who don't even know what the problem is are attempting answers at random, but:

```
<?php

        if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
              header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found")
                die('HTTP_REFERER is not set');
        }

        require_once '../../../app/config.php';
        require_once '../../../app/init.php';

        if (!empty($maintaince)){
              header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found")
                die('maintaince is not set');
        }


        if (!($user -> LoggedIn()) || !($user -> notBanned($odb)) || !($user->isAdmin($odb))){
              header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found")
                die('User not logged in, banned, or isn\'t an admin');
        }


        $username = $_GET['username'];

        if(empty($username)){
              header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found")
                die('username is not set');
        }

        $SQLGetInfo = $odb -> prepare("SELECT * FROM `live_messages` WHERE id = 1");
        $SQLGetInfo -> execute(array($_SESSION['ID']));
        $messageInfo = $SQLGetInfo -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $type = $messageInfo['type'];
        $title = $messageInfo['title'];
        $message = $messageInfo['message'];

        echo json_encode(array(
            'type' => $type,
            'title' => $title,
            'message' => $message,
        ));
        exit();
?>
```

and

```
<script>

window.setInterval(function(){

        var xmlhttp;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET","includes/ajax/user/general/messages.php?username=<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>",true);

        xmlhttp.addEventListener("load", function () {
            if (xmlhttp.status === 200) {
                var res = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                $.toast({
                        heading: res.title,
                        text: res.message,
                        position: 'top-right',
                        loaderBg: '#ff6849',
                        icon: res.type,
                        hideAfter: 6000,
                        stack: 6
                });
            } else {
                $.toast({
                        heading: 'ERROR',
                        text: 'AN ERROR OCCURED' + xmlhttp.responseText,
                        position: 'top-right',
                        loaderBg: '#ff6849',
                        icon: '',
                        hideAfter: 6000,
                        stack: 6
                });
            }
        };

        xmlhttp.send();
}, 5000);


</script>
```